# Use a categorical variable instead of an indicator variable to denote outliers in a regression?

Tags: regression, categorical-data, outliers

I have a question regarding marking outliers using a dummy variable vs a categorical variable:

Suppose I use dfbetas to find outliers in my data and use the rule of thumb |dfbetas| > 2/sqrt(n) to denote a potential influential outlier.

If I understand correctly, one case can have multiple variables and thus one case can have multiple outliers. Therefore I am wondering whether it makes sense instead of including a dummy/indicator variable ‘isoutlier’ 0/1 in my regression, to use a categorical variable ‘outlierness’ in my regression; the higher the value, the more likely the case is an outlier, hence ‘outlierness’.

Does it make any sense to include a categorical variable which denotes ‘outlierness’ instead of an indicator variable that denotes whether or not a case is an outlier in a regression model?

Comment: Please tell us what function these additional variables are intended to serve.  And could you explain what you mean by "one case can have multiple variables and thus one case can have multiple outliers"?  This seems to make little sense in the context of DFBETAS, which flags *the entire case* as influential.

Comment: Data can be influential without being an outlier.  It might be what is called a leverage point.

Comment: @whuber The additional variable 'isoutlier' is an indicator/dummy variable which indicates whether or not a certain/given case has been imputed. This way it's possible to make a distinction between imputed cases and real world cases (that were already present in the dataset). These help me to investigate whether or not imputed cases are of big influence on my model. I though that dfbeta creates a dfbeta per variable per case. For example, running dfbeta after 'regress race male female height' will give you dfbetas for male female and height, which can all have independent outliers?

Comment: @MichaelChernick Thanks for your comment. Good point, I'll look into it. Doesn't dfbeta cover leverage points as well?

Comment: That's not the DFBETA I know, as described at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Influential_observation.  Yes, the *values* of each DFBETA(i) are vectors, but they tell you how much the coefficient estimates change when the *entire* observation $i$ is deleted--and therefore gives you information about the entire observation.  Your comment indicates you might be using the term "outlier" in an usual sense (which includes flagging imputed values), so I recommend explaining in your question exactly what you intend this term to mean.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your comment. Hmm, I might need to do some more reading upon DFBETA. I was under the impression that, since for each variable in the model a seperate DFBETA variable is created, each DFBETA variable indicates how much the value of the variable of a given case is an outlier. What term do you mean by '.... exactly what you intend this term to mean.' ? The term 'isoutlier' or 'outlierness'?

Comment: Either one--it's unclear what you mean by "outlier" or any word related to that one.

Comment: @whuber I think I understand what you mean, please bear with me :) With 'isoutlier' I'm referring to wheter or not the given observation has one or more dfbeta's above the cut-off value (2/sqrt(n)) so that it can be considered as an observation with a high impact on the predictor variable. 1/2

Comment: @whuber Since I defined 'isoutlier' as a dummy/indicator variable, I was wondering wheter or not it makes sense to create a categorical variable called 'outlierness', which counts how many dfbetas are above the cut off point per observation. This way, a higher number indicates that the given observation has (too) much impact on X amount of predictors. I.e. a higher number means the observation is more likely to have (too) much impact on multiple predictors. 2/2

Comment: That's an intriguing idea and can be helpful for data exploration.  What motivated me to ask you about your meaning of "outlier," though, was your comment that said " 'isoutlier' ... indicates whether or not a certain/given case has been imputed."  Since there's no apparent connection between whether a variable has been imputed and its DFBETAS values, this raises questions concerning what you're trying to accomplish and what you conceive an "outlier" to be.  Unless you clarify that in your question, readers could get completely wrong ideas about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57905/discussion-between-freek-and-whuber).